# ACL permission issue on HDFS \ Linux

Tags: hdfs, acl

I have 3 folders structure in HDFS.

- Test

  - Test1

    - Test2

All folders were created by system1 user, and folder owner is system 1 and the group owner is super group.

[image: ls command]

I have update ACL on /test/test2 for user system2 with rwx permission

[image: Get acl]

When I’m trying to run ls command on /test/test1 with system2 I’m getting permission issue

[image: ls command with system2]

I got it working only if I set ACL for system2 user on /test folder – But this is security because system2 user have now the option to browse /test folder

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding, you want to provide access to user `system2` for the directory `test1` without providing the access on `test`.

If this is the case, you have to provide `execute` privilege to user `system2` on `test` directory. So following permissions will be needed for `system2` user.

- test directory - system2 > --x
- test1 directory - system2 > rwx

Now for your security issue, if a user want to access any directory, `execute` privilege is required on all its parent directories i.e., let us take a directory structure `foo/bar/baz`. If you want to access `baz`, you need to have `execute` privilege on `foo` as well as on `bar`. This is because `execute` privilege on a directory represents that a user can access its subdirectories.

So if you only give `execute` to `system2` on `test`, then this user will not be able to do `ls` on `test` directory, since `ls` needs `r-x` privilege.

For reference - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html